# URL.openStream throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, lotus-notes

```
URL url= new URL(url);
url.openStream();
```

I catch an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:727)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:654)
    at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:411)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1022)
    at ImageOptimizer.saveURL(Unknown Source)
```

I run java code on laptop via IBM Notes.
Is it something related to security so I can't open stream with another server?

Comment: Is the server you are connecting to using HTTP?  Looks like the NPE happened when the library was trying to parse HTTP, and if the service you connected to doesn't reply with HTTP data anything could happen.

Comment: Hi Jim

everything works if I run code from Eclipse however when I run code from IBM Notes it gives such issue. I suspect it is something with security but can't prove so far.

Can I change security real time while executing code?

Comment: If was security related, Notes would throw a security exception if your agent is running on the server.  Have you checked the server log, or the java debug console if running from the Notes client?

Comment: I run code locally (from Notes client), and my code suppose to let people save images using URL.
The error in the main description is actually from my local error log.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Patrcik, that log is all what I have :)
I will try to set: permission java.security.AllPermission; just to see if it is realated to security

Comment: I can only assume it's having trouble connecting to the URL you're passing to your saveURL method.

Comment: It has nothing to so with AllPermission, as @Patrick has already told you. It has to do with what the server is sending *after you connect to it.* So you have already connected, so there is no permissions problem. Don't waste your time on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found issue for my case.

I checked version of Java in Lotus Notes and it was 1.5, once I up it to 1.6 it started work properly.
Previously I was not able to change version of java, because it required to add variable to notes.ini:

```
JavaCompilerTarget=1.6
```

Once you add this variable to notes.ini you can set any Java available in Designer.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone .... I've been encountering this exact same issue and despite setting the Java version to 1.6 was still getting the problem. Eventually tracked it down to opening the Java debug console before running the agent thanks to this post from Julian Robichaux http://www.nsftools.com/blog/blog-01-2015.htm . I restarted the Notes client and ran the agent before opening the debug console and was able to open the stream successfully.

Comment: @MartinPerrie - Thanks. I had the same problem with the same solution today.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Notes/Designer
2. Open Task Manager in Windows
3. Find and kill all IBM Lotus Notes/Domino processes
4. Try again